# Code to move all jpeg files to one place.

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to find a non messy way to move all jpeg and other picture files from my c drive in to one folder. prefer to run it as a batch file if possible.

Comment: What is you operating system ?

Comment: so I have one windows 10 machine and one windows 7. sorry forgot to add that to the original post

Comment: Nice that you tell us what you want. Do you have a specific question for that, or do you expect us to write some code for you for free? Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Comment: as the comments below I'm currently doing a course in powershell and my thoughts would be to use xcopy. I just wanted to see how other people would suggest doing it and its my first post on the forum.

Comment: My idea would be to run a simply xcopy as noodles said 
looking like xcopy C:\*.jpg C:\alljpg 
My question would be would this code work correctly or would I need to input more. also is it safe to run this as would it not be scanning that folder also?

Comment: xcopy or robocopy would work fine, however neither deal with name collisions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are tools available to do so, I'm not sure there is a need to built a script.

For example : http://limagito.com/

Comment: I'm trying to have a play around with cmd as, I am currently doing a course in powershell.

Comment: I believe the best way might be xcopy?

Comment: Sorry I'm a Linux user :p

Comment: Thanks anyway! I actually use mac 90% of the time but work requires windows work!

Answer (score 0):

The following scans your C: drive and every folder/subfolder, and dumps the full path and filename of any *.jpeg files into a text file. It then uses that text file to move each file listed within it one at a time to your chosen destination.

```
DIR /S /B %SYSTEMDRIVE%\*.jpeg>"C:\Temp\images_found.txt"
FOR /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (C:\Temp\images_found.txt) do MOVE /Y "%%x" "C:\Destination"
```

Add any file extension you want, you can even scan for multiples by separating them with a semi-colon, eg:

```
DIR /S /B %SYSTEMDRIVE%\*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png;*.gif>"C:\Temp\images_found.txt"
```

If you'd rather copy the files instead of moving them, change the `MOVE` command to `COPY`.